# How to get statuscode in httpcontext after being redirected by AuthenticationHandler in MVC Core

Tags: c#, controller, asp.net-core-mvc, http-status-codes

I've been using `CookieAuthenticationHandler` and am failing authorization by accessing a view handled by a controller method with the `Authorize` attribute.

`CookieAuthenticationHandler` then redirects me to a configurable path in either `HandleForbiddenAsync` or `HandleChallengeAsync` (depending on whether it's authentication or authorization). However, upon redirecting I notice that the HTTP statuscode gets lost.

I've added a breakpoint to the controller action that gets redirected to, where the statuscode is 200.

[image: breakpoint]

I was expecting a different statuscode (401 or 403).

---

This is what happens in `HandleForbiddenAsync` (from [github](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationHandler.cs)):

```
protected override async Task HandleForbiddenAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
{
    var returnUrl = properties.RedirectUri;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
    {
        returnUrl = OriginalPathBase + Request.Path + Request.QueryString;
    }
    var accessDeniedUri = Options.AccessDeniedPath + QueryString.Create(Options.ReturnUrlParameter, returnUrl);
    var redirectContext = new RedirectContext<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(Context, Scheme, Options, properties, BuildRedirectUri(accessDeniedUri));
    await Events.RedirectToAccessDenied(redirectContext);
}
```

So I implemented my own `HandleForbiddenAsync` (with a custom `AuthenticationHandler` that extends `CookieAuthenticationHandler`), and tried to set the statuscode directly by adding this line:

```
redirectContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden;
```

But when I get to the breakpoint I still see statuscode 200.

I'm most likely going about things the wrong way. What I'm trying to accomplish is to get a different statuscode in the controller of my Index view.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you can do achieve the result you want in simple way. Try to return ForBidden() in login action when user authenticate fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've delved through the source code and figured out what's going on.

The statuscode gets changed in `Events.RedirectToAccessDenied(redirectContext);`

It starts in the CookieAuthenticationEvents ([github link](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/Events/CookieAuthenticationEvents.cs))

```
public virtual Task RedirectToAccessDenied(RedirectContext<CookieAuthenticationOptions> context)
    => OnRedirectToAccessDenied(context);
```

into

```
public Func<RedirectContext<CookieAuthenticationOptions>, Task> OnRedirectToAccessDenied { get; set; }
    = context =>
{
    if (IsAjaxRequest(context.Request))
    {
        context.Response.Headers["Location"] = context.RedirectUri;
        context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
    }
    else
    {
        context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
    }
    return Task.CompletedTask;
};
```

This then calls the `Redirect` method of the abstract `HttpResponse` class ([github link here](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions/HttpResponse.cs)) which in this case uses the `DefaultHttpResponse` implementation, which is

```
public override void Redirect(string location, bool permanent)
{
    if (permanent)
    {
        HttpResponseFeature.StatusCode = 301;
    }
    else
    {
        HttpResponseFeature.StatusCode = 302;
    }

    Headers[HeaderNames.Location] = location;
}
```

So the statuscode is changed here, and the redirect statuscodes get picked up by MVC and turned into 200.

If all this is cut out by simply doing the following in the `HandleChallengeAsync` or `HandleForbiddenAsync` methods...

```
var redirectContext = new RedirectContext<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(Context, Scheme, Options, properties, BuildRedirectUri("whatever"));
redirectContext.Response.Headers["Location"] = redirectContext.RedirectUri;
redirectContext.Response.StatusCode = 403;
await Task.CompletedTask;
```

...then the correct statuscode will finally be sent. However, it will now get picked up by the browser instead of MVC, so even though the statuscode is now finally there, the browser will give a default browser error page and that's that.

---

Since what I wanted to do was to get to my redirect page and display a message, I decided to just add the statuscode in the querystring. This is my final `HandleChallengeAsync`:

```
var unauthorizedUri = Options.LoginPath + QueryString.Create("error", "401");
var redirectContext = new RedirectContext<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(Context, Scheme, Options, properties, BuildRedirectUri(unauthorizedUri));
await Events.RedirectToLogin(redirectContext);
```

Then in the controller or view I can simply check the querystring.